# How does one access the raw ECDH public key, private key and params inside OpenSSL's EVP_PKEY structure?

Tags: c, openssl, pki, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I'm using OpenSSL's c library to generate an elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) key pair, following the first code sample [here](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman). It glosses over the actual exchange of public keys with this line:

```
peerkey = get_peerkey(pkey);
```

The `pkey` variable and the return value are both of type `EVP *`. `pkey` contains the public key, private key, and params generated earlier, and the return value only contains the peer's public key. So this raises three questions:

1. How would `get_peerkey()` actually extract just the public key from `pkey` for sending to the peer?
2. How would the code extract the private key and params from `pKey` to store them for later use after the key exchange?
3. How would `get_peerkey()` generate a new `EVP_PKEY` structure from the peer's raw public key?

I've seen the OpenSSL functions `EVP_PKEY_print_public()`, `EVP_PKEY_print_private()`, and `EVP_PKEY_print_params()` but these are for generating human-readable output. And I haven't found any equivalent for converting a human-readable public key back into an `EVP_PKEY` structure.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To answer my own question, there's a different path for the private key and the public key.

To serialize the public key:

1. Pass the EVP_PKEY to EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY() to get an EC_KEY.
2. Pass the EC_KEY to EC_KEY_get0_public_key() to get an EC_POINT.
3. Pass the EC_POINT to EC_POINT_point2oct() to get octets, which are just unsigned char *.

To deserialize the public key:

1. Pass the octets to EC_POINT_oct2point() to get an EC_POINT.
2. Pass the EC_POINT to EC_KEY_set_public_key() to get an EC_KEY.
3. Pass the EC_KEY to EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY to get an EVP_KEY.

To serialize the private key:

1. Pass the EVP_PKEY to EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY() to get an EC_KEY.
2. Pass the EC_KEY to EC_KEY_get0_private_key() to get a BIGNUM.
3. Pass the BIGNUM to BN_bn2mpi() to get an mpi, which is a format written to
   unsigned char *.

To deserialize the private key:

1. Pass the mpi to BN_mpi2bn() to get a BIGNUM.
2. Pass the BIGNUM to EC_KEY_set_private_key() to get an EC_KEY.
3. Pass the EC_KEY to EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY to get an EVP_KEY.

It is also possible to convert the BIGNUM to hex, decimal, or "bin", although I think that mpi used the fewest bytes.

Comment: Deserialize the public key may had worked 4 years and 5 months ago, but it sounds quite complicated today!!! :p EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY is supposed to create EC_POINT from octet but it gets an EC_POINT * from input! I tried to make it by EC_POINT_new but later could not create secret key with the create EVP_KEY!

Answer (score 3):

**OpenSSL 3.x.x**

**To serialize the public key**:

```
// We assume the public and private keys have been already generated.
// EVP_PKEY* keyPair...

// Get the serialized public key length.
size_t serializedPublicKeyLen = 0;
if (EVP_PKEY_get_octet_string_param(keyPair, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PUB_KEY,
    NULL, 0, &serializedPublicKeyLen) != 1) {
  return;
}

// Allocate memory for the serialized public key.
unsigned char* serializedPublicKey = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(serializedPublicKeyLen);
if (serializedPublicKey == NULL) {
  return;
}

// Get the serialized public key.
if (EVP_PKEY_get_octet_string_param(keyPair, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PUB_KEY,
   serializedPublicKey, serializedPublicKeyLen, &serializedPublicKeyLen) != 1) {
  return;
}

// Deallocate the memory when you finish using the serialized public key.
OPENSSL_free(serializedPublicKey);
```

**To deserialize the public key**:

```
// A parameter build for the public key.
OSSL_PARAM_BLD* paramBuild = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();
if (paramBuild == NULL) {
  return;
}

// This is just an example. Set the curve
// you used to generate the public and private keys.
const char curveName[] = "secp384r1";

// Set the curve name to the parameter build.
if (OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string(paramBuild,
    OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_GROUP_NAME, curveName, 0) != 1) {
  OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
  return;
}

// Set the serialized public key.
if (OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_octet_string(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PUB_KEY,
    serializedPublicKey, serializedPublicKeyLen) != 1) {
  OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
  return;
}

// Convert the OSSL_PARAM_BLD to an OSSL_PARAM.
OSSL_PARAM* params = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(paramBuild);
if (params == NULL) {
  OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);    
  return;
}

// Create a EVP_PKEY context.
EVP_PKEY_CTX* publicKeyCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "EC", NULL);
if (publicKeyCtx == NULL) {
  OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
  OSSL_PARAM_free(params); 
  return;  
}

// Initialize the EVP_PKEY context.
if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(publicKeyCtx) <= 0) {
  OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
  OSSL_PARAM_free(params);
  EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(publicKeyCtx);
  return;
}

// Create the peer public key object.
EVP_PKEY* publicKey = NULL;
if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata(publicKeyCtx, &publicKey,
    EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY, params) <= 0) {
  OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
  OSSL_PARAM_free(params);
  EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(publicKeyCtx);
  return;
}

// Free auxiliary things...
OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
OSSL_PARAM_free(params);
EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(publicKeyCtx);


// Now you can use publicKey for EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer.
// Call EVP_PKEY_free when you finish using it.
```

- A full C++ **OpenSSL 3** example: [ec-diffie-hellman-openssl.h](https://github.com/eugen15/diffie-hellman-cpp/blob/main/src/ec-diffie-hellman-openssl.h), [ec-diffie-hellman-openssl.cpp](https://github.com/eugen15/diffie-hellman-cpp/blob/main/src/ec-diffie-hellman-openssl.cpp).
- A full C++ **LibreSSL 3/OpenSSL 1** example: [ec-diffie-hellman-libressl.h](https://github.com/eugen15/diffie-hellman-cpp/blob/main/src/ec-diffie-hellman-libressl.h), [ec-diffie-hellman-libressl.cpp](https://github.com/eugen15/diffie-hellman-cpp/blob/main/src/ec-diffie-hellman-libressl.cpp).

**To serialize the private key**, you get BIGNUM instead:

```
BIGNUM* privateKey = NULL;
EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param(keyPair, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PRIV_KEY, &privateKey);
```

Then, you use one of the BIGNUM serialization function: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/BN_bn2bin.html

**To deserialize the private key**, you use one of the BIGNUM deserialization function from the link above, then push it to the parameter build via OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN with OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PRIV_KEY.

Comment: Just a heads-up for those trying to deserialize the private key: you need to replace EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY by [EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_fromdata.html#Selections), which will work for both public and private keys.

Also, [the public key won't be derived automatically from the private key](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18437) and some functions like EVP_PKEY_print_private_fp won't work directly.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation above seems too complicated. `openssl/evp.h` has functions `i2d_PublicKey()` and `d2i_PublicKey()` to respectively convert to and from a binary representation of the public key (and there are equivalent functions for the private key - see: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/d2i_PublicKey.html)

A small code example:

```
vector<unsigned char> ecdhPubkeyData(EVP_PKEY *key)
{
    int len = i2d_PublicKey(key, 0); // with 0 as second arg it gives length
    vector<unsigned char> ret(len);
    unsigned char *ptr = ret.data();
    len = i2d_PublicKey(key, &ptr);
    return ret;
}

// Make sure you free the returned pointer when you are done with it
EVP_PKEY *ecdhPubkeyFromData(vector <unsigned char> const &pubkeyData)
{       // You do need to put in in an existing EVP_PKEY that is assigned
        // an EC_KEY, because it needs to know what curve you use
    EC_KEY *ec_key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    EVP_PKEY *ret = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(ret, ec_key);
    unsigned char const *ptr = pubkeyData.data();
    d2i_PublicKey(EVP_PKEY_EC, &ret, &ptr, pubkeyData.size());
    return ret;
}
// PS: In a real example you want to check if any of these functions
// return NULL or some error code
```

I am using C++ vectors to contain the binary data, but of course you could just use C-style arrays too :-)

I am absolutely not an OpenSSL expert, so let me know if I am doing something horribly wrong in this implementation :-p

Comment: The question is tagged C, but this is a C++ answer.

Comment: The i2d functions do not return a *raw* key, but a key in some PKCS format (not sure which) according to the OpenSSL documentation. It seems like it might be possible to change the format, but it's not clear how.